# Apply Multiple Filters

Tags: konvajs

Dispite the tutorial here https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/Multiple_Filters.html of using multiple filters, I have been unsuccessful in applying multiple to an image in a NodeJS space.

Here is an example of the "fun" I went through trying to get it to work:

```js
    (Konva, layer, imageNode) => {
      console.log('Callback');
      imageNode.cache();
      // imageNode.filters([
      //   Konva.Filters.Brighten,
      //   Konva.Filters.HSL,
      // ]);

      imageNode.filters([Konva.Filters.Posterize]);
      imageNode.levels(0.8); // between 0 and 1
      // imageNode.brightness(0.8);
      // imageNode.contrast(0.8);
      // imageNode.saturation(0.8);

      // imageNode.cache();
      // imageNode.filters([
      //   // Konva.Filters.Brighten,
      //   Konva.Filters.HSL,
      // ]);
      // imageNode.hue(0.5);
      // imageNode.saturation(0.8);
      // imageNode.luminance(0.85);

      imageNode.cache();
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a mix of brightness, contrast, saturation, hue, lumiance; however some work, some don't, and it all doesn't seem very reliable and if any work, only one ever does.

So how do I for example, brighten, and saturate an image?

Example Image I would like to "bring into the light" by adjusting different factors of it.
[image: Example Image I would like to "bring into the light"]

My end goal is something like this:
[image: Image "brought into the light"]

---

Update #1

No Luck, I cannot even get brightness to work on a small 50x35 image:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8.3.12/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Konva Image Demo</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height,
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();

      // main API:
      var imageObj = new Image();
      
      imageObj.onload = function () {
        var imageNode = new Konva.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: imageObj,
          width: 50, // 2048 / 2,
          height: 35, // 1440 / 2,
        });

          imageNode.cache({ pixelRatio: 1})
          imageNode.filters([
            Konva.Filters.Brighten,
            // Konva.Filters.HSL,
            // Konva.Filters.Invert
          ]);

          // imageNode.filters([Konva.Filters.Posterize]);
          // imageNode.levels(0.2); // between 0 and 1
          imageNode.brightness(0.8);
          // imageNode.contrast(0.8);
          // imageNode.saturation(0.8);

          // imageNode.cache({ pixelRatio: 1})
          // imageNode.filters([
          //   // Konva.Filters.Brighten,
          //   Konva.Filters.HSL,
          // ]);
          // imageNode.hue(0.5);
          // imageNode.saturation(0.8);
          // imageNode.luminance(0.85);

          // imageNode.cache({ pixelRatio: 1})
          
          layer.add(imageNode);
          stage.add(layer);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'C:/Users/<User>/Downloads/Small.png';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update #2
Ok this seems to be firstly an issue with doing this off a local html file, as not even taking the code from https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/Brighten.html and swapping in an absolute path to a file on my machine, works.
[image: Brighten Demo with swapped image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with editing images on a local HTML file, something stops them actually taking the changes.

Comment: Could this be a cross - origin issue, or are all the images from the same host as the page?